# Python account system

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to practice because I'm doing Not Examined Assessment in school and I'm stuck with my code, it doesn't work as intended because it doesn't matter whatever I write in accnick it says that the username is correct :/

```
 acc = input("Do you have an existing account? y/n ")
if acc == "y":
    accnick= input("Enter your username. ")
    while accnick in open("file.txt").read():
        print("Correct username.")
        accpass= input("Enter your password. ")
        if len(accpass) == 0:
            accpass = input("Try again. ")
        while accpass in open("file.txt").read():
            print("Correct password. ")
            break

    else:
        accnick = input("Wrong username, try again. ")

elif acc == "n":
    name = input("Enter your name. ")
    while len(name) == 0:
        name = input("You haven't entered anything, try again. ")
    age = int(input("Enter your age. "))
    age = str(age)
    while len(age) == 0:
        age = input("Enter your age again. ")
    password = input("Enter your password. ")
    nick = name[:3]
    nickname = nick+str(age)
    file=open("file.txt","w+") #w+ is to write to a file and create a file if it doesnt exist yet
    file.write(name+' '+str(age)+' '+nickname+' '+' '+password)
    file=open("file.txt","r")
    kurwa=file.read()
    print(kurwa)
    name = input("Enter your name. ") ###
    if 'Test Test' in open('file.txt').read():
        print("Someone with that name already exists. ")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: When I enter a name not in the file, it tells me that the name is invalid -- i.e. cannot reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code it will jumpback to `print("Correct username.")` after a correct username was typed in. So you are stuck in a endless loop. Your `break` should be part of the while loop. Further I changed the second `while` to `if`.

Try this:

```
acc = input("Do you have an existing account? y/n")
if acc == "y":
    accnick= input("Enter your username. ")
    while accnick in open("file.txt").read():
        print("Correct username.")
        accpass= input("Enter your password. ")
        if len(accpass) == 0:
            accpass = input("Try again. ")
        if accpass in open("file.txt").read():
            print("Correct password. ")
        break
```